# iOS Simulator Shows a Black Screen with "Hello World" project

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I am doing the simplest of projects in Xcode 8.2.1, an "Hello World!" message, but when I run it, although it says that "Build Succeeded", iOS simulator, (for the default iPhone 7 Plus), shows a black screen. When I quit iOS simulator, it says - mach error 308 - ipc/mig - server died.

I see that this question was asked before on the Net, but the suggested methods don't work here. I tried to reset all settings for iOS simulator, and also had a look at the deployment settings for the project. They seem to be ok.

Comment: It would help if the "suggested methods" were listed, because otherwise it makes it difficult to work with.

Comment: Sure, as suggested in similar questions, I tried to (1) reset all settings in Simulator, and (2) had a look at the deployment settings for the project. They seem to be ok. I meant these two. Simulator is also very slow. I cannot think this is its normal behaviour. I am on El Capitan with Xcode 8.2.1. It behaves differently with iPhone 7 and iPhone SE. Any help or troubleshooting idea would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

please make sure you have defined your root view controller or initial view controller